# disable/enable button with tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to disable button when there is no content in tinymce and enable button when there is content in tinymce. I try it like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "mceEditor"
});

tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var hallo = $('#GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').val();
if ($.trim(hallo.value) == "") {
    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr("disabled", true);
}
else
    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr("disabled", false);
```

But when there is no content the button is still visible.

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/xforms_" + StateHelper.GetCurrentCultureName())
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/MailMessage.js"></script>

    <script>
        var generatePdfPreviewUrl = "@Url.Action("GeneratePDFFromHtml", "Product")";

        (function ($) {
            $(function () {

                $("input.datepicker").each(function () {
                    var inp = $(this);
                    inp.datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "@ViewHelper.GetJSLocaleDateFormat()",
                        onClose: function () {
                            $(this.form).validate().element(this);
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
        })(jQuery);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            tinymce.init({
                mode: "specific_textareas",
                editor_selector: "mceEditor",
                setup: function (ed) {
                    ed.on("keyup", function () {
                        onChangeHandler(ed);
                    })
                }
            });



            function onChangeHandler(inst) {
                tinymce.onChangeHandler(ed);
                var editorContent = tinymce.get('GeneratePDFMailFormSubmitter').getContent();
                if ($.trim(editorContent) == '') {
                    alert(editorContent);
                    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    alert(editorContent);
                    $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });  

    </script>
}
```

But it even doesnt hit the    function onChangeHandler(ed) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tinyMCE` provides `setup` option to detect change events in the editor, which you can implement like :

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on("change", function () {
        onChangeHandler(ed);   //<-- This is our Handler
        })
    }
});
```

Now the function `onChangeHandler` will be called every time `tinyMCE` editor's contents are changed. That's where you can check if editor is empty or not and thus, set your button `disabled` or otherwise.

```
function onChangeHandler(inst) {
    var editorContent = tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent()
    if ($.trim(editorContent) == '') {
        $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#btnGeneratePDFMailProductHandler').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Here is the working **[DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/WSeaab/3)**

**UPDATE**

As it was observed that tinyMCE's `change` event requires a click to trigger, we can use `keyup` to trigger the event Handler  :

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('keyup', function(e) {
        onChangeHandler(ed);
    });
}
```

Here is updated working **[DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/WSeaab/4)**

Comment: Thank you Patel. But in you example if you enter text the button will enable, but if you delete the text the button will not go back to disable

Comment: It will go back. But for some reason, it needs a click to activate the change event which is weird. Try clicking after deleting textbox's contents, it will get disabled.

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible I have updated the answer. It works now. :)

Comment: oh, but by me, getContent is not recognisable

Comment: Where is it not recognizable? We solved that in last question, I thought.

Comment: @SavantTheIncredible It works in the demo. Why is there `tinymce.onChangeHandler(ed);` in first line of function `onChangeHandler`? Remove it and it should work. :)

Comment: Ok.Thank you. I will take a look at it.